# Defining the scale function of a diffusion process

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

My question has to do with correctly calculating the **scale function** of a diffusion process, but ultimately might only have to do with calculus. I'll briefly set-up my calculations, so you can quickly see where the problem lies.

Let a diffusion $X_t$ be defined as:
$$
dX_t = 3dt + 2\sqrt{X_t}dB_t
$$

The final objective is to find $\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_0  < \tau_5 \right)$, which by definition is computed as:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\tau_0  < \tau_5 \right) = \frac{s(5) - s(x)}{s(5) - s(0)}
$$
where $s(x)$ is the scale function, defined as:
$$
s(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x}exp\left(-{\int_{y_0}^{y}\frac{2\mu(z)}{\sigma^2(z)}dz}\right)dy
$$

Because the scale function is **unique up to an affine transformation**, one can take any $x_o$ and $y_o$ in the real line. Evidently, $\mu(x) = 3$ and $\sigma(x) = 2\sqrt{x}$. For convenience I take $y_0 = 1$ and obtain the final expression for $s(x)$:

$$
s(x) = \int_{x_0}^{x}exp\left(-{\int_{1}^{y}\frac{3}{2z}dz}\right)dy = \int_{x_0}^{x}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}dy
$$

And here comes the problem:

- if I choose $x_0 = 0$, then I don't have a problem calculating $s(0)$ (which is clearly $0$), **but** now when I calculate 
  $$s(5) = \int_{0}^{5}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}dy  = -\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{2}{0}$$ 
  which is an indeterminate form, which means something earlier has gone wrong.
- if I choose $x_0 \ne 0$, then I face the same problem when calculating $s(0)$.

Now the question is: how can I correctly **separate the calculation of $s(x)$** so that I can obtain two different valid expressions for the scale function, one for the case where $x = 0$ and $x\ne 0$?

Let's see if somebody can help.

Comment: There is a very simple reason for what you are seeing: this process almost surely cannot hit zero if you start from a non-negative number.  I will leave this as as comment in case someone wants to write out the details, but the gist of it is that your drift is always a single positive number and your noise will vanish as $X$ gets close to zero.  Therefore if the process ever gets close to zero, the drift pushes it away from zero.

Comment: I suppose I should have said this in my previous comment.  The scale function is not defined at zero for this process.  If you want to define it consistently as a limit of $s(\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ then the value is $\infty$, not $0$.  Notice that if you formally assume $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ and $\frac{\infty}{\infty} = 1$, this still gives you the correct answer for this problem, which is that $P(\tau_0 < \tau_5) = 0$ and $P(\tau_5 < \tau_0) = 1$.